# Can I make a ngIf using type check (the is keyword) in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a List with 3 items: [Class1 a, Class2 b, Class3 c].
How can I make a switch or ngIf within the template to generate some html based on the type?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="item is CoolClass”>somehtml</div>
    <div *ngIf=item is SomeOtherClass”>some other html</div>
</div>
```

this doesn’t work, it says ngIfIs can not be binded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template expressions don't support is-checks.

Had to make helper functions in my component like isCoolClass and isSomeOtherClass.